# How to get rows in Postgres saving initial order in request?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array of ids:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

and I want to get rows from Postgres table with these ids saving initial order in my array.

To get these rows I use `select * from "table_name" WHERE id IN (ids)`.
After this query Postgres can return rows in this order

> [4, 2, 1, 0, 5]

I know that I can change order to initial by myself, but may be there is a way to use another query to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join against the unnested array rather than using an IN:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
  join unnest(array[0,1,2,3,4]) with ordinality as a(id, idx) on a.id = t.id
order by a.idx;
```

The option `with ordinality` will return the index of each element in the array. And that index can then be used to sort the result.